# Is it possible to earn more than 100 lollipops per second?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have pumped my lollipop rate to 100/s, but it took a long time to go from 99 to 100. Is it even possible to get higher or should I stop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can get more than 100 lollipops/second, but not by planting more lollipops.  100/s is the max base-rate.

To get more, you need to obtain the following items:

- [Shell powder](http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=shell_powder) - 3x Lollipops *(earned by jumping off a dock picking it up from the floor)*
- [Pitchfork](http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=pitchfork) - 3x Lollipops *(earned by entering the castle and finding it - it's in one of the dark rooms)*
- [Green Shark Fin](http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=magical_green_shark_fin) - 5x Lollipops *(earned by jumping off a dock and killing a color-finned shark)*

The items stack, for a total bonus for 45x:

[image: Lollipop production]

---

Note: According to the descriptions, the "Green Shark Fin" is the only fin to give a bonus to lollipops, but there appears to be a bug that causes any shark fin to give the bonus.  In the above picture, I only have the [Red Shark Fin](http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=magical_red_shark_fin)...

Answer (score 5):

The base rate cannot go above 100 lps, however there are three items that increase the rate by a multiplicative factor:

> Shell powder from the sea, a pitchfork from the castle, and the green shark fin.

The first two multiplies the rate by 3, the last by 5 for a total maximum rate of **4500 lps**.

Comment: Green shark fin is 5x on top of that for 4500.

Comment: jump into the sea and once the blue-block-shooting snakes start coming, there will be sharks with colored fins randomly.

Comment: I think you mean the GreenFin. Not the unicorn horn

Answer (score 1):

Lollipops planted : 223 836

Still only getting 100

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Digg a lake (100000 lollipop) and buy lolligators at the lollipop farm. Gators convert candies to lollipops, but you can increase the candy production by the mill. I think, the top rate could be unlimited...

Answer (score 0):

Shell powder triples your lollipops per second.

> Shell powder can be found in the sea.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum lps is 100, for about 23,000 lollipops planted. You can increase it to 4500 by acquiring the green shark fin (kill the green shark in the sea), pitchfork (open a chest in the Castle), and shell powder (found on the floor of the sea).

BTW, can someone tell me how effective lolligators are? I have 19 in my pond, yet my lollipop rate doesn't go up.

Comment: If you want to ask a question, use the 'Ask Question' mothership in the top right.

Comment: If you have another question, ask it using the Ask Question button above right. You can link to this one if it helps you provide context.

Comment: Whoa, @fredley beat me by a few seconds there.