# Quick way to get candies

Tags: candy-box-2

What quest is the quickest way to get candies?I need more candies to get more lollipops, to get the sorceress's hat.

Comment: Also, since you mentioned lollipops, see [Is it possible to earn more than 100 lollipops per second?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137031)